# Geometry of a ball moving inside a equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry

Assume the ball initially is hit at angle $\alpha_0\in(0,\pi)$ inside of equilateral triangle with a side of length $s$, at a point which divides that side to $r_0s$ and $(1-r_0)s$, $r_0\in(0,1)$.

And it starts to bounce inside that triangle indefinitely. It travels a segment of length $x_1$ before it hits the other side at angle $\alpha_1$ at a point which divides that side to $r_1s$ and $(1-r_1)s$ and so on.

Is there a general set of equations describing that movement? Equations that would express $\alpha_i$, $r_i$ or $x_i$ in terms of $s$, $\alpha_0$ and $r_0$. Under what initial conditions after a certain number of steps the movement becomes cyclic (trivial example: $\alpha_0=\pi/3$, $r=1/2$ after three steps)? Can this be generalized to any triangle, a square (quadrangle) or polygon?

Comment: Start with a search for _billiards in triangle mathematics_.

Comment: @EthanBolker do you have any particular references to suggest?

Comment: Fill the plane with reflected copies of your triangle: in that plane the trajectory is a straight line.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca can you elaborate more on this, I don't quite get it. Can you give any reference or a simple example?

Comment: See here, for instance: http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Summer2009/Remus/lesson3.html